# Bootstrap fill gap when input is hidden

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have no experience with bootstrap and I came across with a situation like the following image:

[image]

In the first image the input "manipuleo" is being showed but in the second image I hid it. I want to fill the empty space in the second image with the next input( in this case is "Impuesto Producto"). I´m using Bootstrap and jquery, is it possible?

I show you the code structure that I´m using:

I have no experience with Bootstrap and I came across with a situation like the following image: enter image description here

In the first image the input "manipuleo" is being showed but in the second image I hid it. I want to fill the empty space in the second image with the next input( in this case is "Impuesto Producto"). I´m using bootstrap and jquery, is it possible?

I show you the code structure that I´m using:

@ControlGAS.Office.Resources.Resources.ControlGAS.ComplementaryData

```
    <div id="SectionCommonInputs">

        <div class="form-group form-material floating row">

            <div id="OptHazardousCLSId" style="display:none" class="col-md-4">


            </div>

            <div id="OptWasteMgmtCLSId" style="display:none" class="col-md-4">

            </div>



            <div id="OptHandlingSpecialSCLSId" style="display:none" class="col-md-4">


        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group form-material floating row">

        <div class="col-md-4">


        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">

        </div>


        <div class="col-md-4">

        </div>

    </div>

 </div>
```

Comment: can you give us entire code of your project in form of pen or fiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this structure:

```
<form action="">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="select_id_1"></label>
                <select name="" id="select_id_1"></select>
                <select name="" id=""></select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="select_id_2"></label>
                <select name="" id="select_id_2"></select>
                <select name="" id=""></select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="select_id_3"></label>
                <select class="d-none" name="" id="select_id_3"></select>
                <select name="" id=""></select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

So its not exactly what you have, but it shows you how to order the structure. It is recommended that you give a label for every input, like this rather:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="select_id_1_a"></label>
    <select name="" id="select_id_1_a"></select>
    <label for="select_id_1_b"></label>
    <select name="" id="select_id_1_b"></select>
</div>
```

So when you want to hide a specific input, just give it and its' label a 'd-none' class (bootstrap 4+)